# how to get data in a label to be organized into colums

Tags: c#, type-conversion, multiple-columns, label, do-loops

I am attempting to write a program that will use a post conditional loop. The loop is calculating Celsius to Fahrenheit conversions. I have the equation down but i cannot get the output that way i need it to be.
I need to output both temperatures to the same label while keeping the C and F temps in their own organized column. here is a link showing exactly what i am attempting to do:

[image]

After that, i need to right justify the table while keeping the C temp data in the same place.
I am not sure how to do either of these and apparently after 2 and a half hours of searching on google, it seems google doesnt know either. I am a beginner in C# and i cannot find anything that says how to do this specifically so i can learn to do it myself. Any help will greatly be appreciated. Happy holidays!!!

This is my current code i have, Im still working on it but the data keeps getting bunched together, and i need only to have the words Fahrenheit and Celceius displayed only once at the top

```
double Celceius=0;
double Fahrenheit;
lblOUT.BackColor=Color.Red;

while (Celceius <= 100)
{
    Fahrenheit = 32 + (Celceius * 1.8);

    lblOUT.Text += "Celceius"+ "Fahrenheit"+Convert.ToString(Celceius) + Environment.NewLine + Convert.ToString(Fahrenheit);

    Celceius += 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use String.PadLeft function to pad spaces before your Fahrenheit values. You can give maximum length, 3 in your case, to pad necessary spaces. It will only pad spaces if length is smaller. You can check the details on below MSDN link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Below code will generate the list, **but remember to use font which has equal size for each character such as "Courier New"**

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double Celceius = 0;
        double Fahrenheit;
        lblOUT.BackColor = Color.Red;

        lblOUT.Text = "Celceius" + "".PadLeft(20) + "Fahrenheit";

        while (Celceius <= 100)
        {

            Fahrenheit = 32 + (Celceius * 1.8);

            lblOUT.Text += Environment.NewLine + Celceius.ToString().PadLeft(8,' ') + "".PadLeft(20) + Fahrenheit.ToString().PadLeft(10,' ');

            Celceius += 5;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I have added the code example, but do remember to use font which has equal size for each character such as "Courier New".

Comment: DUDE WOW, you just did everything for me, all i wanted was an example and you gave me the whole kitchen. I hope you have an awesome Christmas now!!!

Comment: Please explain a few things to me. What information is supposed to go into the () after the pad left? I understand what the 20 is, but what represents the (8, ' ') and (10, ' ')?

Comment: 8 is the length of word "Celceius" and 10 is the length of "Fahrenheit". By padding spaces it actually matches with the length of the word, this is why numbers are right aligned with headings. Hope it helps.